# create product shortcode with multiple ids pass in

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I just want to create product shortcode using wp_query and explode but fail. want to call in wordpress posts something like that for multiple products:
[product_data ids="3899,3904,3902,..."] and [product_data ids="3902"] or [product_data id="3902"]for single product.
this is my code so far.
Thanks

```
<?php
add_shortcode('product_data', 'custom_product_shortcode');
function custom_product_shortcode($atts)
{
    
    $productIDS = explode(",", $atts['id']);
    $productData = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'field'    => $productIDS,
    ));
    ob_start();
    if ($productData->have_posts()) : ?>
        <section id="courses" class="courses-slider">
            <div class="courses-list">
                <?php while ($productData->have_posts()) :
                    $productData->the_post();
                    $productImage = the_post_thumbnail($productData->ID);
                    $productTitle = the_title($productData->ID);
                    $productPrice = get_post_meta($productData->ID, '_price', true);
                    $productLink = the_permalink($productData->ID);
                ?>
                  <div class="coursebox">
                        <div class="coursebox-header">
                            <a href="<?php $productLink ?>" class="course-img">
                                <?php $productImage  ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="course-info">
                            <a href="<?php $productLink ?>">
                                <h4 class="course-title"><?php $productTitle  ?></h4>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pop-package-footer">
                            <div class="price-after-discount">
                                <span><?php wc_price($productPrice) ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.dfgfdgfdg.com/cart/?add-to-cart= <?php $productData->ID ?>" class="buy-link">
                                <span class="buy-link-img"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/GeneralRetailStore-Icon-v1.png') ?>"></span>
                                <span class="course-entry-text">buy</span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="<?php $productLink ?>" class="product-link">
                                <span class="product-link-img"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/White document icon.png') ?>"></span>
                                <span class="course-entry-text">Intro</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </section>
<?php endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [`post__in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters) parameter you can pass an array of Post IDs and only get the posts with the ids in the array. The `field` parameter doesn't exist. Your shortcode shows the attribute `ids` but your code tries to get the `id` attribute.

```
$product_ids = explode(",", $atts['ids']);

$productData = new WP_Query(array(
 'post_type'   => 'product',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'post__in'    => $product_ids,
));
```

Comment: Thank. It helps a lot